# Cocoon not adding/deleting fields in nested form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, simple-form, cocoon-gem

I'm building a form in where I can add/delete doses for a cocktail. I'm using cocoon gem but when clicking "add/remove dose" nothing happens in the browser, when clicking "add" no new fields appear and when clicking "delete" the field is not deleted. I don't know why I' not being able to make it work.

I believe this may be related to JavaScript but I'm not really sure how to fix it.

My form partial: _create_edit_form.html.erb

```
 <%= simple_form_for @cocktail do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :name, required: true %>
  <%= f.nested_fields_for :doses do |dose| %>
    <%= render '/cocktails/partials/doses_fields', f: dose %>
  <% end %>
  <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Basic example">
    <%= link_to_add_association 'add dose', f, :doses, partial: '/cocktails/partials/doses_fields', class: "btn btn-secondary" %>
    <%= f.button :submit, class: "btn btn-secondary" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

My partial: _doses_fields.html.erb

```
<div class='nested-fields'>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.text_field :description %>
  </div>
    <%= link_to_remove_association "remove dose", f %>
</div>
```

My application layout

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>RailsMisterCocktail</title>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= csp_meta_tag %>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">

    <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= javascript_pack_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag :cocoon %>
  </head>

  <body>
    <%= render "layouts/partials/navbar" %>
    <div class="page-container">
      <%= yield %>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

My application.js

```
import 'bootstrap';

require("@rails/ujs").start();
require("turbolinks").start();
require("@rails/activestorage").start();
require("channels");

// added for nested forms
require("jquery3");
require("jquery_ujs");
require("nested_form_fields");
require("cocoon");
```

My manifest.js

```
//= link_tree ../images
//= link_directory ../stylesheets .css
//= link cocoon.js
```

Cocktail Model

```
class Cocktail < ApplicationRecord
  validates :name, uniqueness: true, presence: true

  has_many :doses, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :ingredients, through: :doses
end
```

Dose model

```
class Dose < ApplicationRecord
  validates :description, presence: true
  belongs_to :cocktail
  belongs_to :ingredient
  validates :cocktail, uniqueness: { scope: :ingredient }
 end
```

JavaScript console don't output anything when the buttons are clicked

Thanks

Comment: Can you show your relevant models please and output of your javascript console?

Comment: @JoshBrody done

Comment: Looks like you're close. Add `accepts_nested_attributes_for :doses` to `cocktail.rb`

Comment: Now JS console has this output:    

Uncaught Error: 
`Cannot find module 'jquery3'
    at webpackMissingModule (application.js:13)
    at Module../app/javascript/packs/application.js (application.js:13)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19)
    at bootstrap:83
    at bootstrap:83`

Comment: There's some relevant discussion here for similar issues: https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon/issues/537